# Make Sense of ENVIRONMENT for .NET Core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We're now in the era of .NET 8. Can someone clear up some of the following?

Here are at least 3 environment-name environment variables (there may be others):

```
AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments) states that sometimes `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` takes precedence over `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`, and sometimes it's the other way around.

It also states that `IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName` can be set to any value (with the values of 'Development', 'Staging', and 'Production' being provided by the framework), but if neither `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` nor `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` have been set, it will default to 'Production'

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_functions_environment) states that `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` only honors the values of 'Development', 'Staging', and 'Production'. If the value isn't set, or if it's set with an unsupported value, it will use the value 'Production'.

It also states to use this variable instead of `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`. It also links to the other page with contradictory / confusing info where the value can be set to anything.

Imagine a scenario where I have a Function App and I also have a Web App (or API). Imagine also that I want an 'ALPHA' environment. How can I properly go about that for both the function app and the web app?

Answer (score 0):

> if neither `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` nor `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` have been set, it will default to 'Production'

Yes, For the deployed app if we don't set any `_ENVIRONMENT` value, by default it takes the `Production`.

- `AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT` is for Azure Function App.
- Even we can set any other Alpha value other than `Development, Staging and Production` for Azure Function and Azure App Service in `Environment Varaibles` Section.
- Using `IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName` to retrieve Environment name in Function App.

***Function1.cs:***

```cs
  private readonly IHostEnvironment hostEnv;
  public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostEnvironment env)
  {
      _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
      hostEnv = env;
  }
   [Function("Function1")]
 public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
 {   
     var envname = hostEnv.EnvironmentName;
     var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
     response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!" + envname);

     return response;
 }
```

***Function App Initial Output:***

[image]

After setting new value in Environment Variables, you can see the overridden value.

[image]

[image]

- `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is for the .NET Core App and `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` is for .NET Framework Apps.
- Same has to be done for Azure App Service.

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azure_functions_environment), when AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT either isn't set or is set to an unsupported value, it's value will be Production. That has been my experience also.

Comment: Yes...You can see the same in the above workaround

Comment: What is the 'workaround' you are referring to?

Comment: `When AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT either isn't set`

Comment: I'm not following you. What is the workaround If I want the environment to be 'ALPHA' -- other than creating and using my own environment variable. Setting the build-in variable does not work.

Comment: AFAIK,If you want new value other than dev,qa,test,staging and production, setting environment variable is the only option.

Comment: You are wrong about the list of environments. Functions only support Development, Staging, & Production. This is the fundamental problem -- along with the general nonsensical chaos surrounding the unintuitive multiple environment variables.

Comment: Other environments are of Azure App service